# Complex Numbers - Given $(a+b) +i(a-b) = (1+i)^2 + i(2+i)$ obtain the values of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

This would be a very easy complex number question to someone I understand of most of it its just one of those questions I should know but I've stared at it so much I'm stuck! could someone please explain it to me! here it is:

Question - Given $(a+b) +i(a-b) = (1+i)^2 + i(2+i)$ obtain the values of $a$ and $b$. Note $i=\sqrt{(-1)}$

Thank you all! hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: Try expanding the term $(1 + i)^2$ as well as $i(2 + i)$, and separating the righthand side into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Hello again! yes with that i've found that a+b = 0 and a - b = 4?

Comment: so the (1+i)^2 = 2i    and i(2+i) = 2i-1    but im unsure where to go from here, i understand its simultaneous equations but unsure how to go about it

Comment: is your question written correctly? Are you asking for the values of $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $(a + b) + i(a - b) = (1 + i)^2 + i(2 + i)$? If that is your question, then yes you have found the right two equations.

Comment: There is no unique solution.  The left hand side is $(a+b)(1+i)$ and the right hand side is a constant.  So you can solve for $a+b $, but not for $a,b $ separately.

Comment: @hardmath it's not solvable as the right hand side does not equal any $c + ci$ it is $-1 + 4i$ so we have (a+b) = -1 and (a+b) = 4.  But it's been established that the problem was $(a+b) + (a-b)i$ so the yields two equations a+b = -1 and a-b = 4.  which is quite solvable.

Comment: @fleablood: The body of the Question changed, but the original version still appears in the title.  Note that your $c $ could be complex.

Comment: I know.  I was pointing out that not only is there no unique solution there are no solutions at all as the original wasn't redundant but inconsistent.

Comment: Ah yes thank you for letting me know about the title ill change that!

Comment: "that a+b = 0 and a - b = 4".  Not quite.  " (1+i)^2 = 2i and i(2+i) = 2i-1 " Yes.  So "2i + 2i - 1= -1 + 4i".  So a+b = -1 (not 0) and a-b = 4.

Comment: "note that c could be complex"  ...(a + b) = c so (a+b) + (a+b)i = c(1+i) = -1 + 4i.  c = (-1+4i)/(1+i) is complex.  Ooh, that is true!  But I believe the assumption was a and b are real.  Other wise these are *never* solvable.  Which I guess was your point.

Comment: Okay.... we need to note that the assumption is $a, b \in \mathbb R$!  The idea of solving is that (a+b) + (a-b)i = -1 + 4i.  It is assumed $a+b$ is Re(-1 + 4i) = -1 and $a-b$ is Im(-1 + 4i) = 4.  If $a$ and $b$ are not both real we can not assume either $a+b$ is Re(-1 + 4i) nor $a-b$ is Im(-1 +4i).  If not this is not two (real) equations and two (real) unknowns but one (complex) equation with two (complex) unknowns and therefore unsolvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* The trick is to see that the real part of $(1+i)^2 + i(2+i)$ is $(a+b)$, while the imaginary part is given by $(a-b)$. So if you can simplify that equation to be of the form $x+iy$, you then know that $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$, which you then can solve.

Comment: You made a typo.  "(1 + i)^2 + i(2+i)".  Not "(a +i)^2 + i(2+i)".

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do it.

$(1+i)^2 + i(2+i) =$

$(1 + 2i + i^2)+(2i + i^2)=$

$(1 + 2i -1) + (2i - 1)=$

$-1 + 4i$

So $-1 + 4i = (a+b) + (a+b)i$

So $a + b = -1$ and $a+b = 4$.

Well, no wonder you are stuck!  You were given an impossible equation.

====

From your commments it sounds like what you we *actually* given was

$(a+b) + (a-b)i = (1+i)^2 + i(2+i)$

or maybe something else?

You still do it the same way:

$(1+i)^2 + i(2+i) = -1 + 4i$

so $(a+b) +(a-b)i = -1 + 4i$

so $a+b = -1$ and $a-b = 4$.

This is solvable.

$a = - 1 - b$

$-1-b -b = 4$

$-2b = 5$

$b = -5/2$

$a = -1 -(-5/2) = 3/2$.

or....

$a + b = -1$

$a - b = 4$

$(a + b) + (a-b) = -1 + 4$

$2a = 3$

$a = 3/2$

$(a +  b) - (a-b) = -1 -4$

$2b = -5$

$b = -5/2$.

Comment: I think the OP intended the equation in my comment to the original post.

Comment: I think he/she did to but I'm answering what is given...

Comment: Ah no! i've copied it down wrong!! 

been such a long day here we go   (a+b) + i(a-b) = (a+i)^2 + i(2+i) obtain values of a and b

Comment: Apparently the answers we are looking for are a =3/2 and b=-5/2   i dont quite get how though

Comment: It's just a matter of solveing (a+b) = -1 and (a - b) = 4.  Add them to together and you get 2a = 3 so a = 3/2.  Subtract them and you get 2b = -5 so b = -5/2.

Comment: Sorry fairly silly question, how would i know that a+b = -1 and a-b = 4, i understand how to get the values but when i solved..

(1+i)^2 i got 0 + 2i     and when solving i(2+i) i got 2i -1    

Then combined them to get 4i - 1    

How do i know a+b = -1 and then a-b = 4?

Comment: sorry ive just noticed the second i wrote it, its using a + jb, nevermind :D and being that (a-b) is the imaginary the 4i or now 4 must be the (a-b)

Comment: As hardmath pointed out, the assumption is a,b (and a+b and a-b) are real.  A complex number is of the form $z= x + yi$ where x and y are both real.  We call x the real part of z, and we call y the imaginary part of z.  These are both real numbers and they are UNIQUE to z.  so if $z = x + iy = w + ai$ and $x,y,w,a \in \mathbb R$ it *has* to be that $x = w$ and $y = a$ as the real and imaginary parts of a specific complex number are unique reals.  **!!BUT!!!....

Comment: Watch out.  If we say $z = c + i d$ and we *DON"T* point out that c and d are real, and if c and d are complex... well that changes everything  $c = e + i f$ is *NOT* the real part and $d = g + i h$ is *NOT* the imaginary part. (The real part is actually $e -h$ and the imaginary part is actually $f + g$ but I won't go into that right now.)

Answer (score 0):

Generalize the question, when $\text{m}\space\wedge\space\text{w}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\text{q}\space\wedge\space\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\text{m}+\text{w}i=\text{q}^2+\text{z}i$$

We can set:

- $$\text{q}^2=\left(\Re[\text{q}]+\Im[\text{q}]i\right)^2=\Re^2[\text{q}]-\Im^2[\text{q}]+2\Re[\text{q}]\Im[\text{q}]i$$
- $$\text{z}i=\left(\Re[\text{z}]+\Im[\text{z}]i\right)i=-\Im[\text{z}]+\Re[\text{z}]i$$

Now, when $2\Re[\text{q}]=\Re[\text{z}]$ and $\Im[\text{q}]=\Im[\text{z}]$:

$$\text{q}^2+\text{z}i=\Re^2[\text{q}]-\Im^2[\text{q}]-\Im[\text{q}]+i\left(2\Re[\text{q}]\Im[\text{q}]+2\Re[\text{q}]\right)$$

So, now we know:

- $$\text{m}=\Re\left[\text{q}^2+\text{z}i\right]=\Re^2[\text{q}]-\Im^2[\text{q}]-\Im[\text{q}]$$
- $$\text{w}=\Im\left[\text{q}^2+\text{z}i\right]=2\Re[\text{q}]\Im[\text{q}]+2\Re[\text{q}]=2\Re[\text{q}]\left(1+\Im[\text{q}]\right)$$

---

Now, with your information $\text{m}=\text{a}+\text{b}$ and $\text{w}=\text{a}-\text{b}$ and assuming that $\text{a}\space\wedge\space\text{b}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\text{q}=1+i$ and $\text{z}=2+i$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{m}=\text{a}+\text{b}=\Re\left[(1+i)^2+(2+i)i\right]=\Re^2[1+i]-\Im^2[1+i]-\Im[1+i]=-1\\
\text{w}=\text{a}-\text{b}=\Im\left[(1+i)^2+(2+i)i\right]=2\Re[1+i]\left(1+\Im[1+i]\right)=4
\end{cases}
$$

So:

- $$\text{a}=\frac{3}{2}$$
- $$\text{b}=-\frac{5}{2}$$